# exception error: no match of right hand side value []

Tags: erlang

I am trying to see if a letter exists in a list, i am currently doing like the following

```
sortedlist(Text)-> freq(lists:sort(Text)).

freq(List) -> freq (List, [], []).

freq(List, Freq, CheckedLetters) when length(List) > 0 -> 
    [CurrHead|T]= List,
    Checked = lists:member(CurrHead,CheckedLetters),
    case Checked of
            false -> CheckedLetters++[CurrHead],
                    freq(T,Freq++[{CurrHead,count(CurrHead, List)}],CheckedLetters);
            true -> freq(T,Freq,CheckedLetters)
    end;
freq([],Freq,CheckedLetters)-> Freq.
```

- List contains user entered letters
- CheckedLetters is an empty list, that will keep track of the already examined letters

But I am receiving the following erlang exception at the case-statement line (the lines with **).

> error: no match of right hand side value []

What is the problem here? I am been blindy staring at those lines.

Comment: I suspect that either you're misleading yourself and the real error is that `List` is `[]` and so can't ever match `[CurrHead|T]` which can match only a list of one or more elements, or that you're not showing enough of your code to allow anyone to find the real problem.

Comment: included the full code now :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end condition is missing in your recursive function. So when list become empty (each time you recall the function with the tail it is getting smaller), the match `[CurrHead|T]= List,` fails with error.

You have to add a clause to manage the end of recursion:

```
freq([], Freq, CheckedLetters) when length(List) > 0 -> 
    {Freq, CheckedLetters};
freq(List, Freq, CheckedLetters) when length(List) > 0 -> 
    [CurrHead|T]= List,
    Checked = lists:member(CurrHead,CheckedLetters),
    case Checked of
            true -> CheckedLetters++[CurrHead],
                    freq(T,Freq++[{CurrHead,count(CurrHead, List)}],CheckedLetters);
            false -> freq(T,Freq,CheckedLetters)
    end;
```

I think you will have also to review the inside operation, I doubt it is doing what you expect. in particular the line `CheckedLetters++[CurrHead],` has no effect.

**[edit]**
Don't forget that variables are not mutable in erlang. So the line `CheckedLetters++[CurrHead]` simply evaluates a new list and forget the result (in fact I am not sure it does anything since you do not bound this evaluation to any variable, and the compiler knows it).

I guess that what you want to do is:

```
case Checked of
        true -> 
            freq(T,Freq++[{CurrHead,count(CurrHead, List)}],CheckedLetters++[CurrHead]);
        false ->
            freq(T,Freq,CheckedLetters)
end;
```

Next you should have a look at `Freq++[{CurrHead,count(CurrHead, List)}]`, I think it isn't correct.

Comment: Very true, the code is working now, but i see no effect of CheckedLetters++[CurrHead]. any idea why its not working ? what i am doing is trying to add the already examined letters to CheckedLetters list.

Comment: Freq++[{CurrHead,count(CurrHead, List)}] is working as i want , no problem with it at all. Thanks the new code lines you gave me , solved the previous problem. Everything is working now , Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of code in that block that could `error: no match of right hand side value []` is `[CurrHead|T]= List`, as Steve Vinoski said. Likely there is some scenario where `List` is an empty list instead of a list of letters.

Also, the last line in the code block you shared:

```
case Checked == false of
    ...
end
```

Can be simplified to:

```
case Checked of
    true ->
       ...
     false ->
       ...
end
```

Since `Checked` is the return value of `lists:member/2`, and `lists:member/2` is guaranteed to return a boolean, you can safely match directly on the `true` and `false` atoms.

`lists:member/2` documentation: http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2

Comment: Thanks for tip for simplifing the case-statement, List should not be empty, i am putting the userinput in the LIst . i updated the post with the full code for the function, to see it clearly.